# Show that the limit of $F(x,y)=xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ as $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$ exists.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Show that the limit of $F(x,y)=xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ as $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$ exists.

I understand that intuitively this limit goes to zero just by inspection. My issue is I am having trouble getting a $\delta$ estimation. One thing that may help is that I am allowed to use any norm on $\Bbb R^2$ that I wish so I am not restricted to simply the Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ |A+B| \leq |A| + |B|  $$
$$  |x^2 - y^2 | \leq | x^2 + y^2 | = x^2 + y^2 $$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: 
Use polar coordinates to simplify the expression.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align} |F(x,y) - 0| & = \left | xy \frac {x^2 - y^2} {x^2 + y^2} \right |. \\ & \leq \left (\sqrt {x^2 + y^2} \right)^2 \frac {x^2 + y^2} {x^2 +y^2}. \\ & = x^2 + y^2 < \varepsilon. \end{align}$$ iff  $0 < x^2 +y^2 < \delta = \varepsilon.$

This shows that $$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} xy \frac {x^2 -y^2} {x^2 + y^2} = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Basically one has to show :$ \\|xy{\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}-0|<\varepsilon}$

One should note that: $|x|<\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$,  $|y|<\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$  and: $ \\{\dfrac{|x^2-y^2|}{x^2+y^2}<1}$

Therefore , the above inequality turns into : $\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$ *$\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$=$x^2+y^2$<$\delta^2$(The neighbourhood is circular)

where $\delta=\sqrt{\varepsilon}$.
Therefore the limit exitsts and the value of the limit is $0$.